# Multiple synchronized HTML5 audio tracks in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

We have a web application where we load a video along with several audio tracks. They are loaded as `<video>` and `<audio>` elements. We want to play all the audio tracks and the video synchronized, so we want to wait until all tracks are loaded before starting to play.

The problem comes when we have too many audio tracks (more than five).

1. Chrome will start to load the video, and start fetching the first five audio tracks.
2. Once it has received 2 Mb of the audio tracks, it will not attempt to fetch anymore until the audio tracks are played. The connections are not released.
3. The remaining audio track requests are put into "pending" state, because Chrome does not allow more than six concurrent requests to one server.

We are thus stuck in a catch-22: in order for the remaining tracks to be loaded, the connections from the old tracks need to be released. But to do that we must start playing the tracks, which we don't want to do until all tracks are loaded.

By moving the files to different sub-domains we can get around the 6 requests limit, but Chrome also has a global limit of 10 concurrent connections, which we also hit sometimes.

Is there any way to force Chrome to release the connections, and start a new one as needed? Or at least to load the entire file? We have `preload="auto"` on the audio elements, but that seems to have no effect.